# How to Application_End the file app_offline.htm is automatically created?

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax, app-offline.htm, application-onerror

Is it possible?

How to Application_End the file app_offline.htm is automatically created or rename old file to 'app_offline.htm' And in the Application_start to remove or rename this file?

My goal is that the site is down(Application_OnEnd or Application_End) when app_offline.htm is automatically created when the site is up(Application_Start to remove or rename app_offline.htm.

Maybe my words are not true or not the optimal way ... Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: I'm afraid that you question does not make much sense, could you try giving us some examples of what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps some code that you have already tried?

Comment: Ok,Thank you, I will explain more

Answer (score 0):

The `app_offline.htm` is affecting the start and the stop of the application.

So, to trigger the `Application_End` you must have all ready this file on the root, so there is no reason to try to create it again.

And to trigger the `Application_Start` you must have remove the `app_offline.htm`, so there is  meaning to try there to remove it.

So the `app_offline.htm` is start and stop the application.